Acidify My Soil!
What’s my most efficient and cost effective way of acidifying my pH 6.5 soil down to about pH 4.5 for a row of blueberries, maybe 20 ft by 9 inches?
The grow guide the blueberry bushes came with specified pH of 4.5, but it didn’t say how to get there.

Blueberries (even the container-sized cultivars) are all larger than nine inches wide - most are about four feet wide. Lowering the pH 2 full points is really not in the realm of possibility, even with massive amounts of sulfur or ammonium sulfate. Perhaps you should consider growing a couple of container cultivars (like Top Hat) instead; this would allow you to much more easily control the pH of the container's soilless mix.

@Jurp has it all. And if your hydrangeas bloom blue, you are acidic enough for blueberries. Blueberries do great in NJ soil - acid, but not extreme.

See: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/55636/6806 I suppose, (I don't endorse it, but it's basically the same question) but the correct answer is that you should not be attempting to do this with the plants sitting there - you should correct the soil and then order plants.

Dig out a hole, fill with peat (soak the peat well prior to putting it in), then plant the bushes in it. I think we went at least 1.5 foot deep, and something like a 4 by 6 feet in size, for 2 bushes, plus some lingonberries around them. 9 inches is far too small, maybe good enough for the tiny European ones (bilberries?).

By "blueberry" I assume you mean Vaccinium corymbosum. In that case I think you have a bit of an X-Y problem there. You don't want to "acidify" your soil, you should replace it with an appropriate growing medium for the plants you want to grow.
The bushes can easily span 4 feet in diameter, and 9 inches is far too narrow for the root system. I suppose you could fit maybe 6-7 in that 20 foot span, but I would aim for at least a 2-foot wide plot for that purpose. You would dig out all the existing soil there, at least 1.5 feet deep (store it somewhere, it can still be useful).
Based on my research and experience, a suitable medium to grow blueberries in is peat -- both the white peat as well as the Baltic peat are good. On its own the peat is rather nutrient sparse, so it's good idea to mix in some neutral compost, as well as some organic fertilizer (like hoof and horn meal, guano or other dung pellets, etc.).
The peat you will buy is going to be rather dry, and it has an amazing capacity for absorbing moisture. As shipped it's also likely to be quite compact, in which case you should spend some time "fluffing" it up. Spread it out on some tarp, and spray it with water periodically until it's nice and moist, and only then fill the pit you've prepared. Plant the bushes, and fertilize/trim them properly as they grow. You can use compatible mulch to help as well.
The soil is also a great medium for other plants to grown alongside. Lingonberries or bilberries are small and will provide some nice ground cover, and will propagate on their own over time. The small forest strawberries also like it.
